# How would you syntax-color camelcase words in Vim?

Tags: vim

What vimscript command(s) could you use to syntax-color words in CamelCase?

Comment: you might want to create a regex to match camelCase and then create a mapping to this regex to find or highlight camelCase words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `:match` command if you want to highlight words with camelCase:

```
:match Error /\C\<[a-z0-9]\+[A-Z]\w*\>/
```

If you were to use syntax commands you would first need to decide how you want to work in with the existing syntax highlighting for each filetype, but this would give you more control - e.g., only matching camelCase used in names of variables.